# Error 'failed to load external entity' and DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, domdocument

I am having some troubles with loading xml files in DOMDocument on a CloudApp server.
It returns me

> failed to load external entity

With the same piece of code on the same server I sometimes can load the xml file without any issue and sometimes have this error randomly.
The file comes from the client-side, is uploaded, moved into /tmp, and then accessed using `DOMDocument::load()` method. The file I use is always the same.

The server uses `php 5.6.4-4ubuntu6` and the `prefork` module.

I'm particularly concerned by the randomness of this error. Could it be something from a file system configuration, the way it is mounted ?